# Java module path argument confusion

Tags: java, java-module

This question is about the exact syntax of the JDK 14 "java" command.

The [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/specs/man/java.html#standard-options-for-java) states:

```
--module-path modulepath... or -p modulepath
    A semicolon (;) separated list of directories in which each directory is a directory of modules.
```

while java --help on Ubuntu says:

```
-p <module path>
--module-path <module path>...
    A : separated list of directories, each directory
    is a directory of modules.
```

I tried it out using jar files and the separation by colon worked, it didn't work using semicolon. I used jar files, not directories. Is a jar file considered to be a "directory of modules"? Or is it just some undocumented feature that it is possible to use jar files instead of directories? Is there a relation to File.pathSeparatorChar?

Comment: Yes `File.pathSeparatorChar` is the convention for splitting PATH on the operating system and is used as separator for items in classpath and modulepath, and is ';' on Windows but normally ':' elsewhere.

Comment: So the Oracle documentation is wrong?

Comment: Windows uses semicolon separator so it does not confuse with drive letter colon,  so wrong depends which OS you are read the documentation on! But for your first point I don't think jar is being picked up as a directory of modules. Is it possible that the other directories in your module-path are enough to resolve to the modules and any jars you listed were just ignored?

Comment: @DuncG: I have only jars on the module path. The linked Oracle documentation is not OS-specific.

Comment: Yes it does look like the docs needs amending

Answer (score 1):

As you've observed `--module-path` may contain references to directory or jars, I've checked on one of my module jars and it runs fine with this format:

```
java --module-path ..\jars\somemodule.jar;other.jar --class-path ..\jars\non-module.jar main.ClassName
```

It runs fine as this too:

```
java  --class-path ..\jars\somemodule.jar;other.jar;..\jars\non-module.jar main.ClassName
```

But not with the non-module here:

```
java  --module-path ..\jars\somemodule.jar;other.jar;..\jars\non-module.jar main.ClassName
```

And yes as commented above `File.pathSeparatorChar` is the splitter for PATH on the operating system and used as separator for items in classpath and modulepath. Windows ';' but normally ':' elsewhere.